# React Native: Generate Signed APK: Errors while building APK

Tags: android, reactjs, firebase, react-native, android-studio

I have just completed my 1st react native project and now I am trying to generate its APK file by generating a signed APK using Android Studio but I am getting an error and I don't know why I am getting this.

The Gradle build starts running and after that in event log I get an error:

> Generate Signed APK: Errors while building APK. You can find the errors in the 'Messages' view.

In the message view the error that I get is:

> Type io.invertase.firebase.BuildConfig is defined multiple times: F:\Salvador\node_modules@react-native-firebase\app\android\build.transforms\201acb16e5bf3be0b3bc4a9933889ad1\classes\classes.dex, F:\Salvador\node_modules\react-native-firebase\android\build.transforms\9affd011dae86c883f20504c5a21ffef\classes\classes.dex

Comment: try clean build, check if dependency is added twise in package json, also for multiple module check if package name is same or not

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem I have been solving in my projects last days. And I think I have some good (not perfect) solution so far.
**Implementation** in android/app/build.gradle
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture =  false